# How to use AJAX inside Wordpress with a bundler?

Tags: javascript, ajax, wordpress, import, bundler

i recently switched to bundling my JS Files for my themes and tried to always use the Revealing Module Pattern for my scripts to write more organized stuff.

The Ajax File is registered in function.php like this:

```
// Load AJAX
function load_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script('ajax', get_template_directory_uri() . '/src/modules/ajax.js', array('jquery'), NULL, false);
    
    wp_localize_script('ajax', 'wp_ajax',
        array(
            'ajax_url' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php')
        )
    );
}
```

If i try to import my modules in to the ajax File like this:

```
import myScript from './myScript'
```

is throws me this error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: import declarations may only appear at top level of a module
```

How can i use my scripts inside the ajax.js?
I'd like to update some animations etc. after an ajax call and i hate that i need to rewrite the functions inside this file..

Thanks for your time!

Comment: For anyone interested in my current solution:

I'm also bundling the ajax.js file with webpack.

The ajax url is retrieved by setting a global variable inside the header.php

<script type="text/javascript">
    var ajax_url = "<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>";
    </script>

I'd like to know if there is a better solution for the url.

I'm using jquery inside the ajax.js so i'm dequeuing jquery from wordpress and load it inside the webpack.config.js

Comment: plugins: [
            ...defaultConfig.plugins,
            new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
                $: require.resolve('jquery'),
                jQuery: require.resolve('jquery')
            })
        ]

I know its not recommended by wordpress to dequeue jquery, but thats the solution that worked for me, without double importing jquery.